# Redis UNSUBSCRIBE doesn't delete channels

Tags: redis

`sub.unsubscribe` do not delete channels, how can I delete  channels alternatively?

I tried `channel.close()` or `channel.quit()` but that didn't work!

Code:

```
let roomChannelName = room_${roomId}_server;
let sub = redis.createClient(redisConfig);
const channel = this.scServer.exchange.channel(roomChannelName); 
sub.unsubscribe(roomChannelName); 
this.scServer.exchange.destroyChannel(roomChannelName)
```

Comment: Please take a look at [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question.

Comment: what makes you think the channel still exists?

Answer (score 0):

You CANNOT delete a channel manually.

If there's no client subscribes to a channel, Redis will delete the channel automatically.

Comment: `let roomChannelName = `room_${roomId}_server`;                                                        
 let sub = redis.createClient(redisConfig);                                                               
 const channel = this.scServer.exchange.channel(roomChannelName);
  sub.unsubscribe(roomChannelName);
           
  this.scServer.exchange.destroyChannel(roomChannelName);`

Comment: this is my part of code and in this case channels dont removed

Comment: is there a source?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer The source code, i.e. *pubsub.c*, explains everything :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sub.unsubscribe(roomChannelName); 
this.scServer.exchange.destroyChannel(roomChannelName)
```

I'm a little unclear which library this is, but: "destroy channel" **isn't a concept** in redis. A channel is active as long as one or more connections exist that are listening to it (via `subscribe` or `psubscribe`). It doesn't "exist" in any other semantic sense - it doesn't need to be declared ahead of time, nor does it need to be destroyed. If you want to see whether a channel has listeners, you can use either:

```
pubsub numsub {channel name}
```

or, if you don't mind sending dummy data - just publish to it:

```
publish {channel name} {dummy value}
```

either of these will return the count of subscribers for the channel:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> pubsub numsub foo
1) "foo"
2) (integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> publish foo bar
(integer) 0
```

I don't know if your library has an API to expose this, but ultimately: *you don't have to do anything here*. You don't need to clean up after yourself with pub/sub.

If your `sub.unsubscribe(roomChannelName);` call failed to issue an `unsubscribe`/`punsubscribe`, then that is a library issue, not a redis issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can try somthing like that ,
use psubscribe and handle only if the pmesseege enter data
fits your needs..

```
const RedisInstance = require("./redis");
const Subscriber = new RedisInstance().client;
const socketsDataList = require('./activeSocketsList');
const orderManager = require("./orderManager");

class RedisSubscriber {
    subscriber = Subscriber;
    constructor() {
        this.subscriber.psubscribe(`order_*`);
        this.subscriber.on("pmessage", (pattern , channel , order) => this.onOrder( 
       channel , order) );
     }

    async getSocketByDeviceId(deviceId) {
         return await socketsDataList.checkIfSocketExistsForThisDevice(deviceId);
    }

    async onOrder(channel , order ) {
        const deviceId = channel.split("_")[1];
        try {
            const socketObj = await this.getSocketByDeviceId(deviceId);
            if (socketObj['error']) {
                console.log(socketObj['error']);
            } else {
                const socket = socketObj['activeSocket'].socket
                await orderManager.sendOrderToClient( socket , order);
                console.log({message: 'success'})
            }
         } catch (error) {
             console.log(error)
        }
    }
}

 module.exports = RedisSubscriber;
```